# Mobile application Social network module patents

Tags: patent-applications, prior, app, social-networking

There are so many social networking apps available in AppStore and PlayStore. Almost all the modules and features are same in all those apps (like feedpage, photos/videos upload, chatting, etc). So If I create a similar social network mobile application, Will I face any issue related patent or copyright problems?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Will I face any issue related patent or copyright problems?**

This is very hard to say. Almost certainly you should be prepared to do a patent search. Developing within, say Xcode, using the built in functionality ought to be pretty safe from a look and feel perspective. However the underlying logic might run afoul of a patent. There are a lot of patents out there. The fact that multiple apps have similar features is no guarantee of freedom to operate since one app might have licensed technology from the other (or a third party). As for copyright, that is off topic on this site but I would hesitate to just copy another app screen for screen.

Please understand that I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. My own opinion is that it is rather foolish to rely on internet forums and Q&A sites for advice when running a business.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but uploading images/videos are used in almost all social networking application right? In case if someone patent to upload images/videos then no one can develop a social networking app right? And also It's hard to search like is there any patent to upload images/videos or chatting features. How to find those patents?       Thanks,

Comment: @GeorgeWhite In Xcode, Apple's controls are Apple's. They allow you to use them by license and they are either free of outside licenses or Apple has paid those licenses. Same with .Net with Microsoft. It is very important to Apple and Microsoft that their development environments are usable by developers. Of course if you design a custom control it might infringe, but not the stock ones.

Comment: I assume that any useful application will have original code written by the developer. No originality would not make a very valuable app. Any originality is a possibility of infringing.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite But the original question wasn't about originality, it was about using commonly used elements. In context, I think my answer is sound. Basically my answer is there is risk and you should search and consult with a lawyer.

Comment: @Eric Shain - I completely agree with the answer that there is risk and the poster should consult an attorney.  My issue is with the idea that restricting the tools that one uses is much of an insulation against infringement.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I attempted to edit my answer in response to your concerns.